# check if a specific input in an array of inputs is focused Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to test if a specific input in an array of inputs is focused.
In my example i want to to check if the input which have the index [x-1] is focused so i can trigger an event :

```
  if($('.App input')[x - 1].is(":focused")){
        alert('hello');
         }
```

i have tried multiple ways and i am not able to trigger my event 
with this example i am having this exception in the browser's console

Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...)[(x - 1)].is is not a function

Comment: because brackets return DOM not jQuery objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$($('.App input')[x - 1])` so that `$('.App input')[x - 1]` can be considered as a jQuery object and `is` function can be applied. Also, note that the selector is `:focus` and not `:focused`.

```
if($($('.App input')[x - 1]).is(":focus")){
  alert('hello');
}
```

You can also use `eq()` as

```
if($('.App input').eq(x - 1).is(":focus")){
   alert('hello');
}
```

Here is a simple example of it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x=2;
  setTimeout(function(){
    if($('.App input').eq(x - 1).is(":focus")){
     alert('hello');
    }
  },1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='App'> 
<input type='text'/>
<input type='text' autofocus/>
<input type='text'/>
```

Comment: @AmirBouzid glad to help